# recoll executable hogs CPU for days, index dir is 18GB, should I upgrade v1.17 -> 1.20?

Tags: 15.04, recoll

I have some problems with the desktop-search tool "recoll", which comes with ubuntu. (I have 15.04)

Actually, there are several subquestions, but maybe they are all related. I suspect all questions can be solved with an upgrade of the software and a rebuild of the document-index.

I have a recoll index that has grown to 18 Gigabyte file

```
du -sh  ~/.recoll/xapiandb
18G     /home/knb/.recoll/xapiandb
```

This directory contains several subdirs and files.

When the `recollindex` process runs, it runs for days at 100% CPU, it never stops until I kill it with `kill -9 PID`. Why is that so? How to diagnose which files/dirs it is working on, or thrashing on? Research on the internet gives inconclusive answers.
Would rebuilding the index solve the 100%CPU problem?

Is it good practice to exclude this directory from my enterprise backup software (over which I have not much control)?

Should I delete the index from time to time in order to make it more effective? Or, after dropping, would it simpley build the same 18-GB index, or, worse, an incomplete index?

Should I upgrade recoll to the newest version?

Recoll version: Recoll 1.17.3 + Xapian 1.2.19 - default for 15.04.

Wily werewolf , 15.10 will contain Recoll 1.20 anyway.

(according to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/recoll)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not at all normal that recoll would hog the CPU during days, even with a sizeable index. You could check what it is doing by activating the log file, but I think that you should update the version first because 1.17 is ancient.

There are up to date packages for recoll on the recoll backports PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~recoll-backports/+archive/ubuntu/recoll-1.15-on

Once you have upgraded, you should stop the old indexer, delete your index: `rm -rf ~/.recoll/xapiandb` and rebuild it with the new version.

If the problem persists at this point, please use one of the recoll normal support channels, for example, open an issue on bitbucket:
https://bitbucket.org/medoc/recoll/issues?status=new&status=open

Comment: What is the best way to stop the old indexer?

Answer (score 0):

I am using recoll Recoll 1.24.3 + Xapian 1.4.12
I have 32Gb of RAM, an x360 AMD 5200U GPU with 8 processors and it does indeed hog my system.
My solution is to run it with nice

> sudo apt install nice

and start recoll (I use the gui, then start update index from the menu)  with

> nice -n -10 recoll

that brings it down from 100% to 12% of the cpu.
more about nice here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/priority-of-process-in-linux-nice-value/

-n values

-20   most priority  process

20   least priority process

you can change the nice value of a running process with

> renice -15

where pid is the process id.

and alternative is to get the pid from the name

> renice -15 $(pidof recoll)

renice needs sudo privileges though

Comment: It seems odd to me that _increasing_ the process priority would lead  to it using significantly less CPU. In addition, `recollindex` autonices to +19, even when launched from the GUI — even if the `recoll` process has a higher priority. So in terms of the `recollindex` process (which is what this question was about), I'm afraid renicing `recoll` has absolutely no effect other than placebo. (You can view processes' niceness value with `top` or `ps -efl` — a `ps -efl |grep recoll` will show `recoll` at -10, and `recollindex` at 19.)

Comment: Last but not least, a small correction: `sudo` is only required to renice processes to **higher** priority (negative niceness value). Any user can _increase_ the niceness value of any of their own processes without needing superuser privs, which is how `recollindex` automatically renices itself to +19.